# Built-in trackpad and keyboard stopped working on my MacBook when I paired with Bluetooth keyboard and mouse

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, bluetooth

I paired the magic mouse and keyboard from my iMac with my MacBook, now I can't use the built-in trackpad and keyboard anymore. I've tried deleting them from the Bluetooth preference pane but that doesn't fix the issue.

I've used other bluetooth mice and keyboards with this MacBook before and not had this problem. My only thought is that possibly it's related to the fact that the peripherals came with the iMac and my MacBook now thinks that it's an iMac and doesn't have a built-in trackpad/keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable the bottom option in `System Preferences -> Trackpad` (highlighted in red).

[image: Trackpad Dialog]

I highly doubt that your MBP would think it's an iMac. If this doesn't solve the problem, you can head into System Profiler (`Applications -> Utilities -> System Profiler`) and verify that the Apple internal keyboard/mouse is installed as a USB device.

[image: System Profiler]

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in System Preferences that allows you to disable the internal trackpad and keyboard when you connect external ones. You need to disable this.